# There is any option to unsubcribe/unfollow already subscribed community

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, answers, community-user

There is any option to unsubscribe/unfollow already subscribed community in stack overflow (Is this logout is an option for unsubscribing/unfollowing)

Comment: I have no idea what the actual question is here.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. Do you want to remove your user profile, do you want to stop following a question, disassociate from a question, not receive emails? There are so many option where unsubscribe and unfollow can apply so you have to give us a bit more context so we can answer your question. maybe related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: And in case you mean deleting your account on a site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account.

Comment: I Joined 3 of 176 Stack Exchange Sites.And I want to Unsubscribe one of the Stack Exchange Sites

Comment: Is it meant as a question? - *"Is there any option ...?"* In that case, see [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s) (QUASM). You can [edit your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/362142/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing a guess in here (any excuse for a badly drawn red circle) but:

[image]

Will allow you to unpin a community in your sites drop-down.

And navigating to your profile and hitting "Edit profile and settings" will allow you to control your email notification settings:

[image]